# How to listen to push notification dismissed when using OneSignal Ionic SDK,

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, onesignal

So I have noticed that the OneSignal Ionic SDK documentation only specifies two events that you can listen to:

handleNotificationReceived and handleNotificationOpened. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--handlenotificationreceived-

However the OneSignal Web Push SDK has an event called "notificationDismiss" that you can listen to. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk#section-notification-dismiss

Is there a way I can listen to when the user dismisses a notification on the device (by swiping it away from the notification shade) while using the Ionic SDK?

Comment: Is `notificationDismiss ` specific to cordova, or to web?

Comment: Its specific to web.

Comment: There is no such `notificationDismiss` present in ionic in my knowledge. But not sure. But if you can't find a specific solution you can take the help `handleNotificationReceived` i think